# Update query in MS access very slow

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-update

I am trying to use below update query in MS Access to update a field in table tblDM.

```
UPDATE tblDM INNER JOIN tblIS ON ucase(tblDM.PatchDM) like '*'&ucase(tblIS.DMPatch)&'*' 
SET tblDM.Field1 = [tblIS].[Field1]
```

In tblDM there 10,000 records and in tblIS there are 200,000 records.

Above query takes very long to process. I tried running the above query for more than 7 hrs but it was still processing so I have to stop and I am looking for faster options.

Thank you.

Comment: You are doing 2*10^9 comparisons. That's a lot.   
Start with removing `UCase`.

Comment: If you really need to do a substring match, e.g.,`LIKE '*CAT*'` to match 'CONCATENATE',  then there's not much you can do except "tough it out" and run the query. (On my machine it took 6 hours with a local database.) However, if you're looking for keywords within a field, e.g., to match 'DOG CAT FISH' then it might actually be faster to parse out the keywords into a child table and do a JOIN on the (indexed) keyword field.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I used Excel to get the final output though using wild characters in vlookup match formula and it was much faster.